React Typescript как преобразовать тип string в кастомный тип?
onChange={(e) => dispatch(setCardType({id: cardId, type: e.target.value}))} 

Где type свойство моего кастомного типа, пишет Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'quizCardType' Как мне убрать эту ошибку?

Что такое setCardType? Как описана данная функция?

@SwaD это функция в reducers объекте который лежит в объекте переданном функции useSlicer (redux) Кажется я нашел решение, использовать  as Функция принимает параметры (cardId, cardType: quizCardType) .

Вам typescript дан что бы типы проверять, а вы его зачем-то заткнуть хотите. По хорошему надо узнать что за тип quizCardType и почему вы считаете что туда можно заслать любую строку. А если она не любая, то почему вы в этом уверены

@AlexeyTen quizCardType это enum строк, что логично - ведь мне волшебно определенные типы не нужны. Я в input выбираю этот тип  но e.target.value возвращает мне строку что логично. я в input могу как-то указать чтобы варианты были именно типа quizCardType, но как это сделать не знаю, поэтому просто пишу в виде строки

Насколько я знаю нет способа протипизировать input. Тогда действительно остаётся два пути, или as или городит type guard.

Пользователь ведь может ввести любую строку в input, так? Что должно быть, если он введет не то, что допустимо типом quizCardType?

@AndreiKhotko input в моем случае это select.

@Alegro тогда выходит, что только as
